# Contact form 7 dynamic text extension - populate form with title from previous page

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I've looked through the documentation but i can't work out how i'm meant to do this.

I've got a form on a product page which is just a few labels. I want to link them to a contact form and populate the form it goes to with the post title of the product, the page it came from.

So i've got a product page, click on a link, goes to a contact form page with the product (post) title populating one of the fields.

I've looked every where but can't figure out how i'm meant to do this.

I found this page which is supposed to explain how to do this but it doesn't really.

http://sevenspark.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-dynamic-wordpress-contact-form

**Update**

I've got the contact form set up with a CF7_GET key to retrieve the value in the url but i don't know how i get the post title in the url to pass it to the contact form.

Also all of a sudden in the url that goes to my contact form it's putting the current page before the url i define. Does anyone know why it's doing that?

How do i get the post title in the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two steps to this process:

**1. Make sure you have your form set up correctly.**

Your form should include the 'dynamictext' tag, and use the correct syntax as described on the [plugin page](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/). For example, you may want something like:

```
[dynamictext theproductname "CF7_GET key='foo'"]
```

This will set anything after the "foo" $_GET URL parameter (i.e. what comes after "foo=" in the URL http://mysite.com?foo=bar) to be prepopulated into that form field.

**2. Set up your links**

Every place where you link to this page, you must add the product page title to the link. So for example, if the form page is at http://foo.com/?page_id=58, you must add the page title as a parameter and instead link to:

```
http://foo.com/?page_id=58&foo=the%20bar%20of%20soap
```

This will cause whatever you put after "foo=" to appear in the form field defined with the shortcode.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks but, how do i get the link to output the title. It works if i just put some text after foo= but i want it to put the post title in the url so that's what gets put in to the field.