# Add the last viewed post title to a contactform with shortcode

Tags: shortcode, title, plugin-contact-form-7

I'm using the **contactform 7** plugin and i want to add the title of the last viewed page (The page visited before the contact) to the dynamic field of the plugin with a shortcode. Is there a way to do that?

I found this plugin [Last Viewed Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/last-viewed-posts/) to display the last visited post. But I can't found a solution to add this to the dynamic field of my contactform.

Would be very nice if someone could help me.

Thanks, Oli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to do this would be to use the [Contact Form 7 Dynamic Text Extension](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/), and then pre-populate the URL to the Contact Form page with the current post title. More details on how to do that in my answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33109/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension-populate-form-with-title-from-previous-p/33144#33144). The code to pre-populate the link in a post template would look something like:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_page_link(58); ?>&foo=<?php single_post_title(); ?>">Contact Form</a>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping! :) With `get_page_link(58)` have to now the Id of the actual page. Is this right? The Problem here is that my posts are dynamic. So I can't now the ID of the post.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i got it now! 
Like GavinR recommended I'm using now the [Contact Form 7 Dynamic Text Extension](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/)

A very nice tutorial how to work with the plugin can be found [here](http://sevenspark.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-dynamic-wordpress-contact-form).